# Understanding doubly linked circular list

Tags: java, list, linked-list, circular-list

I have an assignment in my CS class about circular doubly linked lists. We are given a Node class that sets up the links and such.

```
public class Node {
private Node previous, next;
private Object data;

public Node(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Node() {

}

public Node(Object data, Node previous, Node next) {
    this.previous = previous;
    this.next = next;
    this.data = data;
}

public Node getPrevious() {
    return previous;
}

public void setPrevious(Node previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

and we are tasked with implementing a few methods. In the list class there is one Node created called 'base'

```
public class DList {



private Node base;

public DList() {

}
```

all of the methods require some form of traversing the list. From what I understand setting up a temp node to be equal to base.getNext() will give me the first node of the list and testing if temp != base will be my check for reaching the end of the list since the base node serves as an anchor for the rest of the nodes (if my understanding is correct).

However, when I try to do bits of code such as:

```
 public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    if (base.getNext() == base)
        return count;
    else {
        Node temp = base.getNext();
        while (temp != base) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I get a null pointer exception at the line where I say Node temp = base.getNext(); and for the life of me I cannot understand why, because like I said earlier I thought that base.getNext() would be the first element of my list.

[image: visualization of CDLL]

Comment: There is no need for a dummy base node. In that case `base` initially is null. So `if base == null ...`

Comment: Well, base has no next. It has nothing ! I suggest you add a method "hasNext" to your Node, it will make your upcoming tasks much easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a dummy base node. In that case base initially is null.
In that case:

```
public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    if (base != null) {
        Node temp = base;
        do {
            temp = temp.getNext();
            count++;
        } while (temp != base);
    }
    return count;
}
```